# Deactivating events with .off

Tags: firebase

Most of my .on events use closures:

```
  ref.on( 'child_added',
          function( snapshot ) {
             userCallback( snapshot.val() );
          } );
```

which means, it is not possible to deactivate these monitors with .off(), since off needs the original callback pointer as well as the eventType.  How can I do this sort of thing?

My app (jQuery Mobile) is page-based.  When the user hits a certain page, I want to activate monitors.  When the user leaves that page, I want to de-activate, so when they re-enter, I don't end up with multiple monitors.  I think I want to call .off() with only eventType and have all callbacks removed.

Comment: This is supported now. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html.

Answer (score 5):

Right now the only option is to store a reference to the callback.  We actually make this a little easier by having .on() return it back to you.  So you can do:

```
var childCallback = ref.on('child_added', function(snapshot) { /* whatever */ });

// later...
ref.off('child_added', childCallback);
```

But we've received several pieces of feedback like yours, saying it is sometimes cumbersome to keep track of your callback references.  So we have a planned API change so that you can call .off() with only an event type or with no arguments at all, and we'll just remove whatever callbacks are registered.  But we're focused on other features right now, so this change is probably 1+ months out.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Has this been implemented (four+ years later)? I haven't tested yet but would be great in my redux app if I could simply call `..ref('/').off()` when routing changes. That way you're only listening for changes to things you're looking at and state isn't changing in the background

Answer (score 2):

In the interim, you can reproduce that sort of behavior with a simple manager pattern. For instance:

```
function ObserverManager( firebaseRef, page ) {
   this.firebaseRef = firebaseRef;
   this.listeners = {child_added: [], child_removed: [], value: [], child_updated: [], child_changed: []};
   this.page = page;
}

FirebaseObservable.prototype.on(event, callback) {
   this.listeners[event].push( 
      this.firebaseRef.on(event, function(snapshot) {
         callback(snapshot.val());
      })
   );
}

FirebaseObservable.prototype.off(event) {
   var list = this.listeners[event], i = list.length;
   while(i--) {  // 50% more efficient than for(i..; list.length; ...) in IE due to scoping
      firebaseRef.off(event, list[i]);
   }
}
```